# How can I determine the resulting numbers for dice throw on an animation?

Tags: animation

I have two normal game dice with numbers 1 - 6. I want throw them. - It is OK. I know how to do that.

The result (numbers on dice when stop) of the throw is random. But I want exact numbers on the dice as a throw result (for example 1 and 5 on dice when animation ends).
Is there any way how to do that? Or I have to try randomly change high of the fall or rotation of the dice on start of the animation and hope it will help?

Thank you.

Comment: Create the animation first, so that you know what faces end up on top. Then assign the material and textures so that they are what you want.

Comment: Smart trick! I have seen this also used in "marble sorting" animations.

Comment: And now I'm wondering if the physics engine could be used to experiment with weighted dice...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Switch your *Transform Orientations* to *Local*, and once your dice has fallen and stopped, go in *Edit* mode and rotate it 180° or 90° or -90° on the right axis until you see the wanted face.

As Robin Betts says, if your cube has small differences of topology between its faces it may change the result, in that case you need to bake the result before rotating the cube.

Or, as suggested by user9746379, simply parent the dice to a basic cube of the same size and that contains it, this parent has the physics, not the dice, once the cube has rolled, rotate the dice as wanted, and at the end only render the dice. This way, the topology differences between faces won't be taken into account.

Comment: Naaah .. use a little script to tweak initial conditions, and keep rendering till it comes right. [See?](https://imgur.com/a/mgqLhz6)....

Comment: wow, nice, why make it simple when you can make it complicated, there's a two though, 5 six would have looked suspicious I guess

Comment: That's the joke ;).. Once I saw your method, I had to give it a go. Funnily enough, if there's the _tiniest_ geometric difference between  the sides of the dice (My dots are concave) you must bake the simulation before making the mesh-rotate. Butterfly effect.

Comment: You're right I should precise that, so did you just bake or did you really use a script?

Comment: Thank you. I tried it and all results are not good. Sometimes it works and sometimes not.

Comment: Of COURSE  I did it your way!!!  XD.. I would have been rendering for _months_ !

Comment: ok I didn't imagine small dots would make any difference, I'm going to roll a real dice several thousand times to see if one face has more chance to win than another ah ah

Comment: I tried to do little modification and it seems it works: Make a dice and make a basic cube only little bigger than dice around the dice (= envelope of the dice). Dice has no rigid body, envelope has rigid body. Set origin of the dice = origin of the envelope. Set transparent material for envelope cube. Start animation and when animation stops, rotate in Object Mode only dice inside envelope cube.

Comment: oh yes of course, and you don't even need to create a transparent material for the parent cube, just don't render it

Answer (score 8):

Create the animation first, so that you know what faces end up on top.

Then assign the material and textures, so that they show the numbers you want.