# Rigid Body Simulation: How to roll the dice to six?

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

this is a generel question for me as a beginner.
How is it posible for a rigid body (like a dice) to land in a specific view, like the six on the top?
I was planing a small project with some cubes. The cubes should fall down from a table on the ground and 6 of them should show a name.
My first idea was to start the animation and at the end, select 6 cubes and add the letters but when I change something of the table or something else, the result is wrong.
So is it possible to 'magnet' a riged body, come hell or high water, the letters are every time shows correct?

Comment: The term you're looking for - Bake the simulation

Comment: read this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/191582/how-can-i-determine-the-resulting-numbers-for-dice-throw-on-an-animation